# React Router 4: Change route with route params with History

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-router-v4

I am new to React framework and right now developing a simple Redux webapp.

If user is on home page (http://localhost/xyz/home) and if I push the next state using history.push('/xyz/profile') I get user id (xyz) in URL twice (http://localhost/xyz/home/xyz/profile)

How can I change the state?

Thanks,
MSK

In action

```
import shareService from "../services/share.service";
import history from "../utils/history";
import _ from 'lodash';

export const shareUserInfo = (info) => dispatch => {
    shareService.shareUserInfo(info)
    .then(res => {
        history.push('/xyz/profile');
    },
    error => {
        console.log(error);
    });
}


In history.js

import { createBrowserHistory } from 'history';

const history = createBrowserHistory();

export default history;
```

Comment: Could you include the code you have written so far in the question?

Comment: @Tholle Added code

Comment: Are you passing the `history` object from `history.js` to your `Router` component?

Comment: @Tholle yes, I am passing it

Comment: Interesting. `'/xyz/profile'` should work. Do you have your developer tools open with cache disabled?

Comment: @Tholle yes, cache is disabled

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/176332/discussion-between-msk-and-tholle).

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to React Router's `match` property, get the url from `match.url`.

*This is not a clean code (as it's just a demo) & some code left out*
The working code is available on [CodeSandBox](https://codesandbox.io/s/717jkwkjo0).

```
const App = ({ match, history }) => (
  <div className="App">
    <h1>Home</h1>
    <h2>Some  data</h2>
    <button onClick={e => toProfile(e, match.url, history)}>Profile</button>
  </div>
);

const toProfile = (e, url, history) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  console.log(`url=${url}`);
  history.push("/xyz/profile");
};

const toHome = (e, url, history) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  console.log(`url=${url}`);
  history.push("/xyz/home");
};

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(
  <BrowserRouter>
    <Switch>
      <Route exact path="/" component={App} />
      <Route path="/xyz/home" component={App} />
      <Route path="/xyz/profile" component={Profile} />
    </Switch>
  </BrowserRouter>,
  rootElement
);
```